# Python - Xlwings wirting issue

Tags: python, xlwings

python code with xlwings running in debug mode but not in the direct run. I see a warning in debug mode as a depricate warning but executes successfully

Am expecting the Xlwing command opens a file and close which was working previously but it is not running currently

Comment: Where is your [example] code? Please add to the Question and format as code. What part of the code is not working, opening the file, closing the file or some operation while the file is open? A Depreciation Warning is just that a warning, the code will still run and operate as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem resolved by doing windows patching.